# What happens to my reputation when a post I edited is deleted by the owner?

Tags: discussion, edits, reputation, deleted-questions

I edited one post; if the owner deleted that post, will I get the +2 reputation bonus? (the edit is still under peer review)

And if I already got +2 for the edit, and user deletes the post, will that reduce my reputation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When a post is deleted, all reputation gained/lost (by the author through up- and downvotes, and by other users through approved edits) is reversed. So, sadly, you will lose the reputation you might have earned. This might seem unfair, but your 'contribution' to the site is lost, and so is the reputation.

Comment: User deleted post when my edit is under peer review  and I got +2 reputation just now.Will that deduct later ?

Comment: @Lakshmi yes. Maybe this is an unusual case, but your [reputation tab](http://stackoverflow.com/users/6623459/lakshmi?tab=reputation) shows a score of +13 2 days ago. This will be corrected later when the recalculation script runs. So enjoy your [upvoting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) while you can!

Comment: Enjoyed by upvoting :)